# How to hide table rows which have their checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have these table rows that have checkboxes:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate, "{0:D}")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organisation.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalExcludingGst)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExportedDateTime)
                </td>
                <td class="centered">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ids" value=@item.InvoiceId />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks a certain button make those rows dissapear / invisible.

So I wrote some jquery:

```
$("#btnexport").click(function () {

        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function (index) {

        });
    });
```

So I'm thinking what this will do is on the button click get all the checked checkboxes which is good. I'm hoping to add to it though so that for each of these checkboxes it will find the associated trs and make those bad boys invisible.

Anyone able to help me out on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$("#btnexport").click(function () {
  $('#idOfTable').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').hide();
});
```

Comment: Of course, you don't want to do a global page-wide query. Instead you want to use a reference to the TABLE element as the context for your query. `$( 'input:checkbox:checked', table )`

Comment: Also, `each` is not needed here, since we're only doing one thing: `$( 'input...', table ).closest( 'tr' ).hide();`. The jQuery methods work on collections of elements just fine.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: it'd be a little (tiny, *tiny* bit) faster to use `$('table').find('input:checkbox:checked')` since that's what jQuery, internally, would convert your approach to anyway.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes. I prefer `$( selector, context )` to `$( context ).find( selector )`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#btnexport").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function (index) {
        $(this).closest("TR").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: The `index` argument is not used and can therefore be left out. Also, I'm not confident that upper-cased type selectors are reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the table rows, and use the `has` method to filter out the ones that have checkboxes that are checked:

```
$("#btnexport").click(function () {
  $('tr').has('input:checkbox:checked').hide();
});
```

Note though:

- Tables are not really made for hiding rows or cells, so you migh experience some layout problems in some browsers.